# Remove footnote

Tags: google-apps-script, footnotes

I have the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
     DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
     .getFootnotes()
     .forEach(f => f.removeFromParent());
}
```

This removes all footnotes. I just want to remove the 2nd of two footnotes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please research before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
     DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFootnotes()[1].removeFromParent();
```